# Display a loading banner with percentage before Next/React has finished loading

Tags: reactjs, next.js, single-page-application

My Next SPA is fetching a 3D Map and data from an API. Is there a way to add a loading banner showing the current percentage of files/components/data loaded before the app is fully loaded?

I'm looking for something similar to this: [Calculate & Display percentage of progress of page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820979/calculate-display-percentage-of-progress-of-page-load)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m thinking of 2 ways to do this, depending on if the data is being fetched during runtime of your app or your app depends on it from root:

1. By using a server side fetcher using a hook (see [load splash screen before nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738909/load-splash-screen-before-nextjs))
2. By fetching the data manually (e.g. literally with fetch), after your app has loaded and tracking progress with `response.body` when using fetch (see https://javascript.info/fetch-progress for reference)